# Unity 3D Door Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written a door script for big vault doors.
My problem is the following: if I assign the script to more than one door
in the scene, all doors open and close together at the same time
that one of them is touched.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BigDoorScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private bool doorOpen = false;
    private Ray ray;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    private float distance = 5.0f;
    public GameObject door;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
        {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, distance))
            {
                if (!doorOpen)
                {
                    door.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f));
                    doorOpen = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    door.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f));
                    doorOpen = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you set the `door` variable?

Comment: Try to make door private instead of public. This may solve the problem of having all the doors activate at once because if it's private only members of that class can access it. Then again I haven't seen the structure of the rest of your code but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your doors open because you're not actually checking whether or not the hit object from your Raycast is actually the door object your script is holding a reference to. Imtiaj touches on this briefly, but string compares on Game Objects are a bad idea and does not limit yourself to one object as many Game Objects an have the same name.

Therefore, any collision will open all of the doors with this script.

You want to use

```
if (hit.collider.gameObject == door)
```

Comment: i add: if(hit.collider.gameObject.name == "door")

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to declare the door gameobject at all. And you can play with the hitinfo ("hit"). Try this -

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BigDoorScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private bool doorOpen = false;
    private Ray ray;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    private float distance = 5.0f;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
        {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, distance))
            {
                if(hit.collider.gameObject.name == "door"){//Check that your ray is colliding with the door
                    if (!doorOpen)
                    {
                        hit.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f));
                        doorOpen = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hit.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f));
                        doorOpen = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But make sure that the name of your door gameobject is "door" without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is your distance value is very big and when you press a door other door in that distance take that hit as well. try reducing that value

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to declare a door GameObject. Just use the `gameObject` property on the monobehavior to move the door the script is attached to:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BigDoorScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool doorOpen = false;
    private Ray ray;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    private float distance = 5.0f;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
        {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, distance))
            {
                if (!doorOpen)
                {
                    gameObject.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f));
                    doorOpen = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    gameObject.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f));
                    doorOpen = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorOpen : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool openclosed;
    public float angle;


    public bool InDistance;

    private void Start()
    {

        openclosed = false;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        InDistance = true;
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        InDistance = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && InDistance == true && openclosed == false)
        {
            openclosed = true;
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, angle);
        }

        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && openclosed == true && InDistance == true)
        {
            openclosed = false;
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, -angle);
        }


    }






}
```

This is a simple open close door script, no animations

Comment: May you show us more about the code? Future visitors may not understand the code at all. Also remove the last `enter code here`.